# Godot - any way to trace signals?

Tags: signals, godot, gdscript

Signals are an essential feature of Godot scripting , but I'm trudging through molasses because of them.

I keep mistaking the names of signals when dynamically connecting and emitting them *(e.g. "start_server" when it was really "create_server")*. On top of that, signals kind of go all over the place. Other messaging patterns I've used typically provide a common publisher for listeners to subscribe to, making it easy to listen on and debug communications. In Godot, everything connects *directly* to everything else. They go up the scene tree, down the tree, and to siblings. Because of this, I'm finding it **very frustrating** to keep track of what's going where once a game gets even remotely large.

I love everything about this engine, but this is maddening.
**Is there a way to track these signals so I can mitigate these small, but very frequent and hard to find signal errors?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is "best practice" but you can make a global gd file for your project that contains constants of all your signal names. If you have a prefix to the signals that you clearly remember it might be easier to have it autocomplete the signal names for you.

e.g.

signal_globals.gd

`const SIG_SERVER_CREATE = "create_server"
const SIG_HABADASHER = "habadasher_crasher"
...
something.connect(SIG_SERVER_CREATE, this, "_create_server_now")`

Although, theoretically the code completion should be able to do signal names by itself already...

Link to setting up [global.gd script](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html#global-gd).

Comment: That's a really good suggestion, but how does one import that global file so the variables are available within my node scripts?  I didn't even know that was possible within GDScript...

Comment: Here's a [link](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html#global-gd) to how you can setup a globally accessible .gd file to all your scripts.